# Appending the mysql select result by group condition

Tags: mysql

I'm making a report where i need to summarize the results by joining several tables to get results by grouping the cd.line_id condition.
following is my select query.

```
SELECT bp.broadband_name,cd.line_id FROM broadband_service_master bp,dedint_account_services_table_wireless_pbx dp,
dedint_account_services_table das,dedint_account_table da,csr_deposit_change_history cd
 WHERE  bp.broadband_service_id=dp.service_id
 AND dp.dedint_service_table_id=das.id
 AND das.account_id=da.id
 AND cd.line_id=da.account_id
 GROUP BY cd.line_id
```

I'm getting this :

```
broadband_name        line_id  
--------------------  ---------

Equipment Support        344065
OffNet Landline Call     344065
Excess ONNET Calls       344065
Equipment Support        344066
International Call       344066
OffNet Landline Call     344066
Unlmtd ONNET Call        344066
```

I need results like this:

```
broadband_name                                             line_id  
--------------------                                      ---------

Equipment Support,OffNet Landline Call,Excess ONNET Calls    344065

Equipment Support,International Call ,OffNet Landline Call,Unlmtd ONNET Call 344066
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..`GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(bp.broadband_name),cd.line_id FROM broadband_service_master bp,dedint_account_services_table_wireless_pbx dp,
dedint_account_services_table das,dedint_account_table da,csr_deposit_change_history cd
 WHERE  bp.broadband_service_id=dp.service_id
 AND dp.dedint_service_table_id=das.id
 AND das.account_id=da.id
 AND cd.line_id=da.account_id
 GROUP BY cd.line_id
```

Comment: @Baljot let me know if it helps